# Combine arrays PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I have tree arrays like this

```php
$keys = array("elment1","elment1","elment2","elment1");
// This one can have duplicates values
$operator = array("=","<",">","=");
// Operators for MySql query 
$queries = array("query1","query2","query3","query4");
// This one can have mixed values
```

I want to know how to combine this tree arrays to have a query like this:

```
$string = "SELECT FROM tables
           WHERE
           (elment1 = query1 OR elment1<query2 OR elment1=query4)
           // For the group of duplicates keys
           AND
           elment2 > query3";
           // For the non duplicates
```

I need this for multi-filter queries.

The user should push a button to add `keys`, `operator` and `query` as many times as he like.

I'm using jquery to create `form` elements, and `each()` function to generate 3 arrays, before posting all to php.

Comment: what language is this? Please write your question in english.

Comment: I know enough to know it is French, but not enough to know what the question is.

Comment: Google Translation: http://bit.ly/clD20G

Comment: I know enough to answer the question, but will he be angry if I answer in English?

Comment: I know enough PHP to code something for his specific example but I don't know enough french to explain why I believe he needs to rethink his idea

Comment: So only french developers are supposed to answer :)

Comment: I don't understand a word but my guess is the answer is `implode()` :)

Comment: @Pekka: You're right! @Cfreak: Me neither, but how could he rethink his idea, and why? Security concerns?

Comment: mhmm, baguette(); where is Pascal Martin if you need him? Last seen seen 11 hours ago, so I doubt we can conjure him to here.

Comment: If only there was a French dialect of SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonjour,

Here is the code. tried and tested.
Voila le code... essayer avec succé

```
$keys = array("elment1","elment1","elment2","elment1");
// this one can have duplicates values , 
$operator = array("=","<",">","=");
// operators for Mysql query 
$queries = array("query1","query2","query3","query4");
// mixtes values

$joined = array();
for($i = 0, $size = sizeof($keys); $i < $size; ++$i)
{
    $joined[$keys[$i]][] = $keys[$i] . $operator[$i] . $queries[$i];
}

foreach ($joined as $key => &$value)
{
    $value = implode(' OR ', $value);
    $value = "(" . $value . ")";
}
$query = implode(' AND ', $joined);
print $query;
```

Comment: attention a le code "foreach ($joined as $key => &$value)" avant $value il y a "&". cela remet la valeur attaché dans $joined.
in front of $value there is an '&' this stores the value back to the array $joined.

Comment: use 'view source' to view the actual output.. the '<' and '>' signs hide the string in the browser

Comment: thank you so much  Anand , this work perfectly 
i've tested with random arrays , it's just works 
thanks

Comment: finally i've integrate your code in my application , thanks
it works like i excepted , nice work

Answer (score 4):

You asked a question in French, I'll answer in English and you can use Google Translate if you need a translation. [Utilisez Google Translate pour traduire cette réponse si vous voulez.]

First of all, you'll need to concatenate the pieces. Pay attention to the `mysql_real_escape_string`, which makes the whole operation a little bit safer.

```
$joined = array();
for($i = 0, $size = sizeof($keys); $i < $size; ++$i) {
    $joined[$i] = $keys[$i] . " " . $operator[$i] . " '" . mysql_real_escape_string($queries[$i]) . "'";
}
```

Then you can use `implode`:

```
$string = 'SELECT [...] WHERE (' . implode(' OR ', $joined) . ')';
```

Comment: thanx for your response and sorry for my french 
your code is very handy , but this will add OR for all keys 
i want do that for duplicates keys only 
and by default use AND for non duplicates ones:

$string = "SELECT FROM tables 
           WHERE
           (elment1 = query1 OR elment1<query2 OR elment1=query4)
           // if i have other duplicates it will be 
           AND
           (KEY1 = query OR KEY2=QUERY)
           AND
           elment2 > query3";